# How to use apply() to add new columns with condition of standard deviation?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a function, and a rule to be applied on df.

```
def apply_rule(df, rule):
    df['legal'] = df.apply(rule)

def greater_than_mean_plus_1_std():
    return df['col1']>df['col1'].mean()+df['col1'].std()

apply_rule(df, greater_than_mean_plus_1_std)
```

I want to apply rule on my df that can make me a new column that tells me if the value of row is greater than mean+std or not.

But with df.apply(), I can't use df.mean() and df.std() here.

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

Is there a way to do so? Or I have to use methods other than df.apply()?

edited:

```
print(df.head())

   col1
0   7.2
1   7.2
2   7.2
3   7.2
4   7.2
```

expected output:

```
   col1  legal
0   7.2  False
1   7.2  False
2   7.2  False
3   7.2  False
4   7.2  False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
def apply_rule(df, rule):
    df['legal'] = rule(df)  # <- change here

def greater_than_mean_plus_1_std(df):  # <- change here
    return df['col1'] > df['col1'].mean() + df['col1'].std()

apply_rule(df, greater_than_mean_plus_1_std)
```

Output:

```
# df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': range(10)})
>>> df
   col1  legal
0     0  False
1     1  False
2     2  False
3     3  False
4     4  False
5     5  False
6     6  False
7     7  False
8     8   True
9     9   True
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `apply` here

```py
df['legal'] = df['col1'] > (df['col1'].mean()+df['col1'].std())
```

If you want to use `apply`, you can use DataFrame.apply on rows or Series.apply

```py
df['legal'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['col1'] > (df['col1'].mean()+df['col1'].std()), axis=1)
# or
df['legal'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x > (df['col1'].mean()+df['col1'].std()))
```

Answer (score 0):

calculating mean and std value first,

```
col1_mean = df["col1"].mean()
col1_std = df["col1"].std()
```

Then use these pre-calculated value in apply like this

```
df["legal"] = df["col1"].apply(lamdba x: x > col1_mean + col1_std)
```

and If you want to make it functional you can use lambda:

```
col1_mean = df["col1"].mean()
col1_std = df["col1"].std()
greater_than_mean_plus_1_std = lambda x: x > col1_mean + col1_std

def apply_rule(df, rule, column):
    df['legal'] = df[column].apply(rule)
```

Now to call this apply_rule

```
apply_rule(df, greater_than_mean_plus_1_std, "col1")
```